# Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery() in spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
@Modifying
@Query
(value="update userremedy set assign_to='?' where remedy_id=?",nativeQuery=true)
public List<UserRemedy>update(String assignTo,Long RemId);
```

what iam supposed to do in spring boot i have added both @modifying and @Query

Comment: What is the problem you are observing?

Comment: thank you for replying, i was missing with @transactional ,added it and it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

You should use named parameters, and modifing queries return the number of modified rows, so try somethiing like

```
@Modifying
@Query
(value="update userremedy set assign_to=:assignTo where remedy_id=:remId",nativeQuery=true)
public int update(@Param("assingTo") String assignTo, @Param("remId") Long remId);
```